# iOS right side whitespace after CSS3 animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

On the website https://swap-n-sell.com does the right side get a whitespace on iOS. In other browser it works. The whitespace appears when I open the sidebar and close it with the button on the top left corner:

[image]

The sidebar opens/closes with a CSS3 animation. After it's closed I get on the right side this whitespace:

[image]

I inspected it with the Webinspector and added `margin-right: 0%;` to the body. Suddenly the whitespace was removed but when I opened the sidebar again then the whitespace was also again there. Maybe the view doesn't refresh or something like that I don't know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I solved it with z-index. So that the sidebar doesn't cause any problems with device-width or viewport-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overlay has those values in the CSS:

```
height: 3799px;
width: 1280px;
```

Will those values be removed after the navigation has been closed again?

On a different note:
I get the feeling that the site is measuring my viewport and then adds those values to the CSS. So when I resize my browser-window, the overlay will stay the same width causing massive issues (for example I can't close the navigation anymore). I don't know if the values for the viewport of an iOS device will be computed the right way. May be it's the device-width and not viewport-width?

Comment: Shouldn't the whitespace be removed if they have `display: none;`?

Comment: I don't fully understand what's going on but I have what you are referring to as whitespace on both sides of the main content when opening the navigation.

It seems this might be related to falsey computing when it comes to the viewport-dimensions on the iOS device. If I do not resize my viewport, all is looking well.

I'm on Firefox 39 (Mac OSX, 10.8.5).

Comment: Which device do you use and which OS?

Comment: Just so I get this off my chest: you should look into a solution, which does not rely on Javascript in the first place.
Build the nav without Javascript and then enhance it. =) Much better way to go because you have a robust foundation first and then you can paint the walls (so to speak).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your bug but I would bet on `overflow`.

Try adding an `overflow-x: hidden;` to your body or inspect the white space to know which **div** create the problem and try to play with `overflow-x` on this **div** as well.

Good Luck'

Comment: There is nothing inside the whitespace. `overflow-x: hidden;` sadly doesn't work on the body. Thanks for helping.